# ApprovalForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

this is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Request,Query,Approval
class RequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
           model = Request
           fields = ('reqtype','priority','sample','description','status')`
```

this is my view in views.py

```
def req_detail(request,pk):
    req = get_object_or_404(Request, pk=pk)
    form = ApprovalForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid:
        req.isapp = form.cleaned_data['isapp']
        if req.isapp:
            req.assgto = form.cleaned_data['assgto']
        req.save()
    return render(request,'manage/requestdetail.html',{'req':req,'form': form})`
```

it is giving error Cleaned_data no defined attribute in approval form.Why?

Comment: `form.is_valid` is a function. Since you're not *calling* the function, you're evaluating the function *name*, which will happily always be `True`. Thus when you reach `form.cleaned_data`, the form has not yet been validated, and no `cleaned_data` attribute exists.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `form.is_valid` should be `form.is_valid()`. The reason is that the value returned by `form.is_valid` is not `None` which evaluates to True always and since the function has not been called, `cleaned_data` is not filled with the validated data.